# How to send video file to Firebase database & storage in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am working on a photo and video sharing android app and using Firebase as my database and storage. In my ShareActivity a user can choose either Image capture or video recorder and send it to database+storage. When using image everything works fine but not able to send video file.
Below is my ShareActivity codes

```
private static final String TAG = "Camera Tag";
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseShare;
private StorageReference mStorageShare;
private EditText mTitle;
private ImageView mTitleImage;
private Button bShare;
private Button mRecordBtn;
private Uri mFileUri;

private ProgressDialog mProgress;
private VideoView mVideoView;
// Activity request codes
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

// directory name to store captured images and videos
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Media Files";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);

    mTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    // imageview to start camera
    mTitleImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.titleimage);
    // pushes data to firebase
    bShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnshare);
    // Videoview for preview
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.uservid);
    // starts video recording
    mRecordBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonrecord);

    mDatabaseShare = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("SharedMedia");
    mStorageShare = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mDatabaseShare.keepSynced(true);

    mProgress  = new ProgressDialog(this);

    mTitleImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showImagePicker();
        }
    });

    bShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            shareMedia();
        }
    });

    mRecordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            recordVideo();
        }
    });
}

private void recordVideo() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    mFileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

    // set video quality
    // 1- for high quality video
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);

    // start the video capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}

private void showImagePicker() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    mFileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

}

private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int mediaTypeImage) {


    return  Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(mediaTypeImage));
}

// Button click method to send data to firebase
private void shareMedia() {

    final String name_title = mTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    mProgress.setMessage("Please wait");
    mProgress.show();


    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name_title) && mFileUri != null){

        StorageReference filepath = mStorageShare.child("Shared_Media").child(mFileUri.getLastPathSegment());

        filepath.putFile(mFileUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                DatabaseReference newShare = mDatabaseShare.push();

                newShare.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                newShare.child("video").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());

                mProgress.dismiss();
                startActivity(new Intent(ShareActivity.this,MainActivity.class));

            }
        });

    }


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // video successfully recorded
            // preview the recorded video
            previewVideo();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled recording
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to record video
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

}

private void previewVideo() {
    try {
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(mFileUri.getPath());
        // start playing
        mVideoView.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void previewCapturedImage() {

    try {

        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        mTitleImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", mFileUri);
}

/*
 * Here we restore the fileUri again
 */
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    mFileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}

/*
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: I recommend watching Zero To App (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE) and checking out it's associated source code (https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c).

Comment: Posting a trace in LogCat would be more helpful.